# In creating a Google Scholar profile, should I use my personal email address or my university email address?

Tags: google-scholar

I want to create a Google Scholar profile. As far as I can tell, such profiles are not transferable from email address to email address.  Should I use my personal email (Gmail) account, which I will hopefully have for the rest of my life?  Or should I use my university email, which is actually hosted and maintained by Google?  I am a post-doc and will be at my university for the foreseeable future -- probably for a few years, but not forever.

- I have a personal Gmail account (e.g., `johndoe@gmail.com`).
- My university's email addresses are hosted by Google. (My university email address is `jdoe@myuniversity.edu`, but it is hosted and maintained by Google

Comment: It may not be, even if you use Gmail to access it - my old university would let you use Gmail unless you were under HIPAA, in which case you had to use office or some terrible old email program from the early aughts.

Answer (score 13):

**Your personal account.**
You will then have the option to add and verify an institutional e-mail to it, inside Google Scholar. This adds a text "verified e-mail on myuniversity.com" in your profile.

Not everything in our future is foreseeable, even for those with tenure, and universities are particularly eager to deactivate old institutional addresses, for no good reason in my view.

Comment: You make a great point that the future is not really foreseeable.

Comment: I might have bolded the second sentence, rather than the first, because although the first sentence is indeed the more direct answer, I think the explanation that there is a verification opportunity for other institutional addresses when you use an account with another email is the key info that someone not familiar with Google Scholar should learn.